# Passing dict to constructor?

Tags: python, dictionary, constructor

I'd like to pass a dict to an object's constructor for use as kwargs.

Obviously:

```
foo = SomeClass(mydict)
```

Simply passes a single argument, rather than the dict's contents. Alas:

```
foo = SomeClass(kwargs=mydict)
```

Which seems more sensible doesn't work either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use :

```
foo = SomeClass(**mydict)
```

this will unpack the dict value and pass them to the function.

For example:

```
mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

SomeClass(**mydict) # Equivalent to : SomeClass(a=1, b=2)
```

Comment: Greetings from the future! Sorry for taking four years to mark this as the accepted answer :^)

Answer (score 3):

To pass a dictionary to a constructor you have to do so by reference, which is by preceding it with `**`, like so:

```
foo = SomeClass(**mydict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`SomeClass(**mydict)`